# Circular-reference error that doesn't appear to exist in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, circular-reference

I've been scratching my head for a while at this one.  No Idea.

I have a function which returns a javascript object, ready to be delivered to the JSON.stringify function.  When I do I get a circular-reference error.  It appears that the 'callWidget' method is returning an anonymous function which I don't want.  I just don't see the error.

```js
function putAnswersTogether() {
    var answers = [];

    $(".addedquestion").each(function(i, e) {

      var answerJSON = {qname: $(e).find(".questionname").val(),
          answerid: $(e).attr("answerid"),
          answer: callWidget($(e), "getResponse", "")};

      answers.push(answerJSON);
    });

    return answers;
  }
  
function callWidget(questioncontroldiv, method, value) {
 var divtype = $(questioncontroldiv).attr('id');
 var result;
 switch(divtype) {
 case "mogrify-multiplechoice":
  result = $(questioncontroldiv).multiplechoice(method, value);
  break;
 case "mogrify-checkbox":
  result =  $(questioncontroldiv).checkbox(method, value);
  break;
 }
 return result;
}

// The following methods are contained within widgets for multiplechoice and checkbox

_getResponseJSON: function() {
    var qname = this._getQuestionName();
 var answers = [];
   
    this.options.questioncontrol.find(
      "input[name='optradio-" +
      qname +
      "']:checked"
    ).each(function(i,e) {
        answers.push($(e).val());
    });
    
    return answers;
  },

_getResponseJSON: function() {
    qname = this._getQuestionName();
    var answer = this.options.questioncontrol
        .find("input[name='optradio-" + qname + "']:checked")
        .val();
   
 return answer;  
},
```

Comment: If callWidget return a function, .multiplechoice() or .checkbox() probably also returns a function. What do those methods do? Do they return the JQuery function maybe?

Comment: Only a pass-through method that links to the functions given above ("this._getResponseJSON()")

Answer (score 0):

You are already passing a jQuery object from function **putAnswersTogether** to **callWidget**

```
answer: callWidget($(e), "getResponse", "")
```

so remove jQuery tags from **callWiget** funciton

```
var divtype = $(questioncontroldiv).attr('id');
```

Comment: Can you reproduce that somewhere like jsfiddle